# Files to array - glob vs RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I'm adding a list of files to an array by doing:

```
$files = glob($path."*.*");
```

I can output the array with `print_r(array_values($array));`.

Now I'm trying to do the same with `RecursiveIteratorIterator`:

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)
);
```

That does not work like expected when I try to output the array?

```
print_r(array_values($files));
```

How can I get the same result?

Comment: `$files` is an iterator, not an array.

Comment: You need to iterate over it with `foreach`.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please elaborate? I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: `array_values` works on arrays. `$files` is a `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, which is an iterable object, not an array. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php#refsect1-recursiveiteratoriterator.construct-examples) for examples of how to use it. `array_values` actually isn't necessary to `print_r` the result of `glob`, incidentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators are not the same as arrays. To use an iterator, you have to iterate over it with `foreach`.

```
<?php
$path = "test.dir";
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)
);
$file_array = array();
foreach ($files as $f) {
    $file_array[] = $f;
}
print_r($file_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/.
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => .
        )

    [1] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/..
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => ..
        )

    [2] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub1/.
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => .
        )

    [3] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub1/..
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => ..
        )

    [4] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub1/filea.jpg
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => filea.jpg
        )

    [5] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub1/fileb.jpg
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => fileb.jpg
        )

    [6] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub2/.
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => .
        )

    [7] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub2/..
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => ..
        )

    [8] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub2/sub21/.
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => .
        )

    [9] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub2/sub21/..
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => ..
        )

    [10] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.dir/sub2/sub21/filee.jpg
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => filee.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: I've tried that now but the array is empty when I do `print_r(array_values($file_array));`.

Comment: I just tried it, it works for me. Maybe you didn't give a correct `$path` when you created the iterator.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks for the help!